# Issue in brfs plugin of browserify

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, browserify, brfs

I am trying to convert all .html template files in to a single bundle.js file by reading file content from each .html file.

I wrote following code in `main.js`

```
var fs = require('fs');
var templates = {
    'header': fs.readFileSync('app/templates/header.html', 'utf8'),
    'heading': fs.readFileSync('app/templates/heading.html', 'utf8')
}
```

This is working but adding some unnecessary wrapper functions in `bundle.js` when I run `browserify -t brfs main.js > bundle.js` in cmd:

```
(function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof require=="function"&&require;if(!u&&a)return a(o,!0);if(i)return i(o,!0);var f=new Error("Cannot find module '"+o+"'");throw f.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",f}var l=n[o]={exports:{}};t[o][0].call(l.exports,function(e){var n=t[o][1][e];return s(n?n:e)},l,l.exports,e,t,n,r)}return n[o].exports}var i=typeof require=="function"&&require;for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)s(r[o]);return s})({1:[function(require,module,exports){

var templates = {
    'header': "<div class=\"headerSection\">\r\n\t<div class=\"headerSectionWrapper\">\r\n\t\t<div class=\"logo\">{{name}}</div>\r\n\t\t<div class=\"searchBarSection\">\r\n\t\t\t<div class=\"searchBar\">\r\n\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t\t<div class=\"searchTextHolder\">\r\n\t\t\t\t<form name=\"searchform\">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<input type=\"text\" name=\"searchbox\"></input>\r\n\t\t\t\t</form>\r\n\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t</div>\r\n\t</div>\r\n</div>",
    'heading': "<!-- HTML Template -->\n<h3>heading</h3>\n"
}
},{}]},{},[1]);
```

How to remove this wrapper functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just run `brfs` directly:

```
$ brfs main.js
var templates = {
    'header': "<div class=\"headerSection\">\r\n\t<div class=\"headerSectionWrapper\">\r\n\t\t<div class=\"logo\">{{name}}</div>\r\n\t\t<div class=\"searchBarSection\">\r\n\t\t\t<div class=\"searchBar\">\r\n\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t\t<div class=\"searchTextHolder\">\r\n\t\t\t\t<form name=\"searchform\">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<input type=\"text\" name=\"searchbox\"></input>\r\n\t\t\t\t</form>\r\n\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t</div>\r\n\t</div>\r\n</div>",
    'heading': "<!-- HTML Template -->\n<h3>heading</h3>\n"
}
```

The `brfs` command ships with the brfs package.

Comment: that is showing result in command prompt.. How to include in other file like bundle.js ?

Comment: Figured it out..  `brfs main.js > bundle.js` :D. Is there any way to run it dynamically? I mean I have many .html files in a `template` folder. I want to keep a for loop in `main.js` which will convert it to any array/object of templates in `bundle.js`?

Comment: I am using `watchify` instead of `browserify` now. I know `watchify` is just `browserify` but it will look for changes everytime. Can you please tell me how to watch this expression? `brfs main.js > bundle.js`.

Answer (score 1):

That's the browserify prelude code. It's the "runtime" that makes browserify work. You get it even with a tiny example:

```
echo 'console.log("foo")' | browserify
(function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof require=="function"&&require;if(!u&&a)return a(o,!0);if(i)return i(o,!0);var f=new Error("Cannot find module '"+o+"'");throw f.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",f}var l=n[o]={exports:{}};t[o][0].call(l.exports,function(e){var n=t[o][1][e];return s(n?n:e)},l,l.exports,e,t,n,r)}return n[o].exports}var i=typeof require=="function"&&require;for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)s(r[o]);return s})({},{},[]);
```

It is unrelated to brfs, just browserify, and it's the magic that makes browserify work in browsers and node.

Comment: How to  remove this prelude code? I honestly don't want this prelude code.  Till now I was doing as mentioned by @substack in his answer. but that will not work in my current situation because I am using now `watchify` to do batch operations. Hence, I am ended using `watchify -t brfs main.js -o bundle.js` instead of `brfs main.js > bundle.js`.